# What do each of these experimental goog- RTCPeerConnectionConstraints do?

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc

From various examples, sites, forums, discussions, and source codes, I've compiled this list of experimental google RTCPeerConnection constraints. What do each of them do in the context of a WebRTC RTCPeerConnection?

```
peerConnectionConstraints:
    optional: [
        #goog experimental
        { googIPv6: true }
        { googImprovedWifiBwe: true }
        { googDscp: true }
        { googSuspendBelowMinBitrate: true }
        { googScreencastMinBitrate:400 }
        { googCombinedAudioVideoBwe: true }
        { googCpuOveruseDetection: true }
        { googCpuOveruseEncodeUsage: true }
        { googCpuUnderuseThreshold: 55 }
        { googCpuOverUseThreshold: 85 }
    ]
```

Answer (score 12):

Most of these options are non-documented. Some of them used for Google's products such as Hangouts.

**googIPv6** - enables support of IPv6 for Chrome (should also work in latest Firefox)

**googImprovedWifiBwe** - Chrome has bandwidth estimation algorithm, and this flag enables improved (but experimental) version of the algorithm. In the latest version of Chrome this flag is on by default, - the
experiment was successful.

**googDscp** - enables [DSCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiated_services)

**googScreencastMinBitrate** - Used by Hangouts application. Sets the minimum bitrate for screensharing.

**googCpuOveruseDetection** - if enabled, Chrome will lower outgoing video quality and video resolution

**googCpuUnderuseThreshold** - the min CPU load (percents), used in pair with googCpuOveruseDetection

**googCpuOverUseThreshold** - the max CPU (percents), used in pair with googCpuOveruseDetection

**googCpuOveruseEncodeUsage** - don't know

**googSuspendBelowMinBitrate** - the minimal bitrate for considering session is alive (not sure)

**googCombinedAudioVideoBwe** - don't know

Comment: googSuspendBelowMinBitrate - when enabled, this causes the video track to be automatically disabled if the detected bandwidth drops below "min bitrate" (whatever that value is, configurable via x-google-min-bitrate)

Comment: this website also has so many useful information about webrtc and specifically these flags. http://www.rtcbits.com/